# Ceate Laravel email verification url for each subdomain

Tags: laravel, email, verification

how  can i create Laravel email verification url for each user depends of user subdomain. eg : user1.domain.tld, user2.domain.tld ...
In my current case this url generated with main domain.
and `APP_URL` is as same as my own main domain.

Thank you